# Set the content of Label to Image's Tooltip

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I am using IValueconverter interface to change the tooltip text of an image.
The tool tip should change based on label.

```
<Label Content="9898980001" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="1733,231,0,0" Name="lbl02scanning" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="Blue" >

<Image Height="49" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,131,113,0" 
       Name="img02scanning"
       Source="/TEST;component/Images/LoadingStation.png" Stretch="Fill" 
       VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Cursor="Hand">
    <Image.ToolTip>
        <StackPanel Background="AliceBlue">
            <TextBlock Padding="5" Foreground="White" MinHeight="20"
                       Background="Blue" FontWeight="Bold" 
                       Text="Scanning Station" />
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image 
   Source="pack://application:,,,/TEST;component/Images/coilonsaddle_large.png" 
   Height="100" Width="100" />
                 <TextBlock Padding="10" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
                            MaxWidth="200" Background="AliceBlue"
                            Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold"
                            Text="{Binding ElementName=lbl02scanning, Path=Name, 
                                           ConverterParameter=255,
                             Converter={StaticResource FormatterFOrCoilToolTip}}"/>                                       
              </StackPanel>
              <TextBlock Padding="5" Foreground="White" MinHeight="20" 
                         Background="Blue" FontWeight="Bold"
                         Text="Report to admin in case of coil location mismatch"/>
         </StackPanel>
    </Image.ToolTip>  
</Image>
```

The converter class:

```
 public class FormatterForCoilToolTip : IValueConverter
    {

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

      if(parameter.ToString() == "02")
      {
      return value.ToString() + " Startin";
      }
      else
      {
      return value.ToString() + " Finishing";
          }
    }


    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The tooltip's Textblock content is not changing. But if i change to:

```
Text="{Binding  ConverterParameter=255, Converter={StaticResource FormatterFOrCoilToolTip}}
```

then it is working. But i want to pass the lbl02scanning text value. Why it is not working??

Comment: Where is `lbl02scanning` declared? Can't find in posted XAML.

Comment: @RohitVats in the same form.. now update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should bind to `Content` property and not `Name` property in case you want Text of Label.

Most importantly **Tooltip does not lies in same Visual Tree as that of label**, hence binding with elementName won't work. However, you can use [x:Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the element even if it doesn't exist in same Visual Tree.

```
Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference lbl02scanning}, Path=Content, 
               ConverterParameter=255,
               Converter={StaticResource FormatterFOrCoilToolTip}}"/>
```

**Note - x:Reference is introduced in WPF 4.0. If you are using WPF 3.5 you can't use this.**

---

**Update** for error - *service provider is missing the name resolver service*

Just found out bug is reported at [Microsoft site](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/660141/visual-studio-2010-invalidoperationexception-using-x-reference-in-wpf) that `x:Reference fails in case Target is Label`. However, i couldn't reproduce this issue at my end since i have WPF 4.5 installed at my end and i guess they have fixed the issue in future version.

In case you target WPF 4.0, i would advise you to use `TextBlock` in place of `Label`:

```
<TextBlock Text="9898980001" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           Margin="1733,231,0,0" Name="lbl02scanning" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           Foreground="Blue" />
```

and then bind with `Text` property instead of `Content`.

```
Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference lbl02scanning}, Path=Text, 
               ConverterParameter=255,
               Converter={StaticResource FormatterFOrCoilToolTip}}"/>
```

Either, you can refer to workaround provide under workarounds section [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/660141/visual-studio-2010-invalidoperationexception-using-x-reference-in-wpf).

You can override the ProvideValue method of the Reference class and skip the reference search login in design time:

```
[ContentProperty("Name")]
public class Reference : System.Windows.Markup.Reference
{
    public Reference()
        : base()
    { }

    public Reference(string name)
        : base(name)
    { }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        IProvideValueTarget valueTargetProvider = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IProvideValueTarget)) as IProvideValueTarget;

        if (valueTargetProvider != null)
        {
            DependencyObject targetObject = valueTargetProvider.TargetObject as DependencyObject;

            if (targetObject != null && DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(targetObject))
            {
                 return null;
            }
        }

        return base.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
    }
```

---

**Update with another workaround**

*This will work for all versions WPF 3.5, WPf 4.0 and WPF 4.5*.

> **First** of all bind Image Tag with content of label.
>
> **Second** host your stackPanel inside ToolTip control so that you can
>   take benefit of PlacementTarget property.
>
> **Third** bind with PlacementTarget.Tag of Tooltip.

Relevant code will look like this:

```
<Image Tag="{Binding ElementName=lbl02scanning,Path=Content}">
   <Image.ToolTip>
      <ToolTip>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                                    Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ToolTip},
                                    Path=PlacementTarget.Tag,
                                    ConverterParameter=255,
                           Converter={StaticResource FormatterFOrCoilToolTip}}"/>
       </ToolTip>
   </Image.ToolTip>
</Image>
```

Also you need to update converter code to put null check over there since PlacementTarget will be null until you open tooltip.

```
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (parameter.ToString() == "02")
            {
                return value.ToString() + " Starting";
            }
            else
            {
                return value.ToString() + " Finishing";
            }
        }
        return String.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: its showing "service provider is missing the name resolver service"

Comment: Updated with few more approaches. See if that helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
Text="{Binding Path=Content,ElementName=lbl02scanning, ConverterParameter=255, Converter={StaticResource FormatterFOrCoilToolTip}}
```